# How to access $rootScope within ng-view, but outside controller scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm attempting to access a `$rootScope` variable within `ng-view`. The problem is that I'm trying to access it on an HTML element that is not within any controller's scope. Is this possible?

Here's the HTML snippet that appears within `ng-view`:

```
<tab heading="Account" ng-if="devMode">
  <dm-user-account ng-if="devMode"></dm-user-account>
</tab>
```

The `ng-if` works on `dm-user-account`, but not on the `tab`.

Comment: This smells like a good candidate for a directive.

Comment: make your directive priority lower than ng-if priority 600

Comment: what do you gain by using `$rootScope`? you don't even show what you are using it for here;  There are very few valid reasons to use `$rootScope`, it is not meant as a pseudo replacement for a global object.